# Handler for custom event not firing: "Cannot call method "apply" of undefined error instead

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

For every view in my app, I am trying to create an `fhActivate` and `fhDeactivate` event for when views are created & destroyed so I can execute different necessary functions. In my main controller, after I create a view, I execute this:

```
view.fireEvent('fhActivate');
```

And in another controller, I am trying to listen for the event like this:

```
config: {

    refs: {
       rankings: {
             selector: 'fhrankingspanel',
             xtype: 'fhrankingspanel',
             autoCreate: true
        }
    },

    control: {
        rankings : {
            fhActivate: 'onRankingsActivate'
        }
    },


    onRankingsActivate: function() {
        console.log('activate');
    }
}
```

The view is loaded fine, and the xtype is defined in that class like this:

```
alias: 'widget.fhrankingspanel'
```

But I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined
```

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

I will also note, I have tried this within the control config object:

```
rankings : {
            fhActivate: this.onRankingsActivate
        }
```

And I also tried setting my ref to something simple:

```
rankings: 'fhrankingspanel'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It also helps if you do not wrap your methods within the config object. I noticed my stupid error when referring back to the docs here:

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller

Once I changed that, and made my control method look like this, it worked:

```
control: {
        rankings : {
            fhActivate: 'onRankingsActivate'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This Error occurs when the callback method is undefined. You likely have either a typo or a scope issue at the point where you register a event.

In your case you should first try to write this.onRankingsActivate instead of 'onRankingsActivate'

Comment: I thought this was the case too, and it probably is. But I tried your suggestion and it still gives me the same error. I don't think it's a typo though, b/c I c&p'd all names a 2nd and 3rd time to rule that out.